# Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} is triggered through any button which has type="submit" or not specified or after enter on textbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, formik, react-final-form

I'm trying to get submitter/caller of `<form onClick={handleSubmit} />`
In event arg I would like to check 'id' of caller button e.g. `<button id="submitter">Submit with id</button>` and allow continue only if 'id' match.

I have tried Formik, Final-Form, Redux form and also standalone `<form>` tag.
Even pressing enter on input tag will trigger submit form. I understand that this is default behavior but I need to restrict which caller is allow to continue.

I have to use tag `<form>` otherwise something like scroll to closest error doesn't work. Tried with Final Forms.

In my application I have lot of bottons for adding fields to array removing and not all of them has type="button" which will prevent this. But as I said even enter on textbox will trigger this onSubmit so I have to find better solution.

Keep in mind that I can't avoid using `<form>` tag.
Thanks

https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-jackson-2m4r5

```
<form
      onSubmit={e => {
        e.persist();
        e.preventDefault();
        // HOW TO GET id="my-submit-button" HERE ???
        console.log(e);
        if(id==='my-submit-button') handleSubmit()
      }}
    >
      <input type="text" name="firstName" />

      <button>Button without type</button>
      <button type="button">Button type=button</button>
      <button type="submit">Button type=submit</button>
      <button id="my-submit-button">Button with id</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What does e.target say?

Comment: form - and thats the probblem, I haven't found any information about button or textbox who trigger that action

Comment: Maybe `document.activeElement` or `event.currentTarget`

Comment: Yes document.activeElement works great !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use event on click:

```
<form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" />
  <button>Button without type</button>
  <button type="button">Button type=button</button>
  <button type="submit">Button type=submit</button>
  <button id="my-submit-button" onClick={() => {
    console.log("Button click");
    // handleSubmit()
  }}>Button with id</button>
</form>
```

Comment: As I mentioned above I have to keep onSubmit on form tag otherwise feature provided on FinalForm doesn't do focus on error.

Answer (score 0):

As @epascarello mentioned this works -> document.activeElement